# Возникает проблема парсинга даты и времени, не понимаю в чем проблема

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

В чем может быть проблема?

```
  raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Fri, 06-Nov-2020 21:36:45 GMT' does not match format '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Comment: У меня проблемы нет, приведите [mcve] для её воспроизведения

Comment: В том и дело, что и у меня все работало. И я понять не могу, в чем проблема. Есть строка на выхода, вот она и функцию парсинга

Comment: Питон очень странно себя ведёт

Comment: приведите ваш код, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в локали -- она поменялась. Эти `%a` и `%b` напрямую от локали зависят ([ссылка на похожую проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174131/5909792)).

Как вариант, можно принудительно указывать локаль через `locale.setlocale` для значений даты и времени через `LC_TIME`, либо для всего `LC_ALL`.

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT
import locale


def check():
    try:
        print(DT.datetime.strptime("Fri, 06-Nov-2020 21:36:45 GMT", "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'[-] {e}')


check()
# 2020-11-06 21:36:45

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru')
check()
# [-] time data 'Fri, 06-Nov-2020 21:36:45 GMT' does not match format '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
check()
# 2020-11-06 21:36:45
```